# Updating the table and displaying the current data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dataset, sql-update

I am trying to update the table which is working but after updating I cannnot see the updated data on the form when I ho to next record and comeback eventhough it gets updated on sql server.
Here is my code

```
    Try
        cn = Connection.connectionstringESLC()
        cn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "Update [School Admin Aug 2012] SET NAME='" & txtName.Text & _
            "' , ADDRESS = '" & txtAddress.Text & _
            "' , [Alternate Email] = '" & txtEmail.Text & _
            "' , [ADVISOR NAME] = '" & txtAdvName.Text & _
            "' , [DEPT NAME] = '" & txtDept.Text & _
            "' , PROGRAM = '" & txtDegree.Text & _
            "' , DEGREE = '" & txtMajor.Text & _
            "', MAJOR = '" & txtProgram.Text & _
            "', [DATE ADMITTED] = '" & dtpAdmitted.Value & _
            "', [ADMISSION DECISION] = '" & cmbAdmDecision.Text & _
            "' , [ENROLLMENT STATUS] = '" & cmbEnrollment.Text & _
            "', [CAMPUS] = '" & cmbCampus.Text & _
            "' , [ADVISING SHEET DATE] = '" & dtpAdvshtdt.Value & _
            "' , [GRADUATION DATE] = '" & dtpGrdDt.Value & _
            "' , [CURRENT POSITION] = '" & txtCurrentPosition.Text & _
            "' , [GRE] = '" & txtGRE.Text & _
            "' , [SLLA] = '" & txtSLLA.Text & _
            "' , [KYPT] = '" & txtKYPT.Text & _
            "' , [COMMENT] = '" & txtComment.Text & _
            "' WHERE [MNUMBER] = '" & txtMNumber.Text & "'"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        cn = Nothing

        MsgBox("Record updated successfully")
        loadinfo()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

**' I am also running loadinfo() code on page_load function**

Public Sub loadinfo()
        Try

```
        cn = Connection.connectionstringESLC()
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from [School Admin Aug 2012]")
        cmd.Connection = cn

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "dbo.School Admin Aug 2012")

        da.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()

        If i < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
            txtMNumber.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)

            txtName.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1))
            ' IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2))

            txtAddress.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2))

            txtEmail.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3))
            txtAdvName.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4))
            txtDept.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5))
            txtProgram.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(6)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("PROGRAM"))
            txtDegree.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(7)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("DEGREE"))
            txtMajor.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(8)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("MAJOR"))
            dtpAdmitted.Value = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(9)), "12/31/9998", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(9))
            cmbAdmDecision.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(10)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(10))
            cmbEnrollment.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(11)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(11))
            cmbCampus.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(12)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(12))


            dtpAdvshtdt.Value = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(13)), "12/31/9998", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(13))
            dtpGrdDt.Value = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(14)), "12/31/9998", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(14))
            txtCurrentPosition.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(15)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(15))
            txtGRE.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(16)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(16))
            txtSLLA.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(17)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(17))
            txtKYPT.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(18)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(18))

            txtComment.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(19)), " ", ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(19))
            cn.Close()
            cn = Nothing
        ElseIf i < 0 Then
            i = 0
        Else
            MsgBox("This is the last record")
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: I am using sql server 2012

connectionstring = "Data Source=VENKY-PC;Initial Catalog=ESLC;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"

Comment: Excluding problems with the connection string and not having any error message due to invalid characters in your textboxes, then the only possible reason is an invalid record number in the WHERE clause. I suggest to use the debugger, put a breakpoint on the first line of this code and check the value of the `txtMNumber.Text`. However this will be better if recoded using a parameterized query

Comment: By the way, you are passing all of your values as string between single quotes. Are your table fields of text datatype. It is very prone to error when you use a string to search a numeric value. (MNUMBER is a numeric field?)

Comment: I have kept MNumber to be a stribg value. I guess the problem is with the data set. Since I am filling the dataset on formload and then updating, it cant erase the previous dataset and fill it with newone